# Как добавить рекламу в приложения с Youtube API?

Tags: android, google-play, youtube, youtube-api

насколько я знаю в том году запретили использовать youtube API в приложениях вместе с монетизацией, не пропускают такие приложения на google play. Может есть какой нибудь выход, как обойти это и все таки добавить рекламу в приложения с youtube API?

Comment: Вариантов много, но зачем? Заметят — в лучшем случае заблокируют приложение, в худшем — вызовут в суд.

Comment: А можно парочку вариантов назвать хотя бы?

Comment: главная задача — это "засунуть" приложение в магазин. Можно пойти по пути Дмитрия, можно изначально вставить рекламу, но включать только, если сервер даст "согласие". Суть заключается в том, чтобы узнать, как вычисляют такие приложения и скрыться от метода вычисления.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант 1 версию загрузить без рекламы , а в обновлении добавить

Answer (score 1):

Сейчас у меня есть приложение с youtube API в котором показывается реклама admob, претензий по этому поводу ко мне не предъявляли.

Answer (score 0):

На экране видео, на котором воспроизводится видео на YouTube, не может быть никаких рекламных объявлений. Поэтому разместите свои объявления только в тех местах, где нет видео с YouTube.